# How to install imagemagick on centos 8?

Tags: centos, imagemagick

I tried with :

```
dnf install GraphcsMagick

yum install ImageMagick
```

Got always: Unable to find a match

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm -y
dnf install GraphicsMagick
```

@yarek
you have a typo (GraphcsMagick) it should be **GraphicsMagick**.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick is in EPEL repository[1].
You have to enable EPEL repository in order to install it[2].

[1] https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/i/ImageMagick-6.9.10.64-1.el8.x86_64.rpm

[2] https://www.linuxtechi.com/enable-epel-repo-centos8-rhel8-server/